# Why isnt this recursive algorithm working properly

Tags: python, algorithm

Ive written a recursive algorithm to delete any duplicates from a sorted list

```
def removeDuplicates(nums):
        def helper(nums,value=1):
            if value == len(nums):
                return nums
            if(nums[value] == nums[value-1]):
                del nums[value]
                return helper(nums,value+1)
            else:
                return helper(nums,value+1)
        return helper(nums)
```

For an input of `[0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]`,
an output of `[0,1,2,3,4]` is expected.
But instead an output of `[0,1,1,2,3,4]` is supplied
Why isnt it working for triplets

Comment: When you delete an item, realise that the next item after that ends up at the index you just deleted, so you should not make the recursive call with `value+1`, but with `value`. Secondly, there is a much easier way to do all this: [remove duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Comment: @trincot, thanks worked perfectly

Comment: Or just: `list(set([0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]))`

Comment: @jarmod yes, but its an algorithmic problem on leetcode, that i have to solve manually

Comment: Since you are doing this recursively for what seems like a study exercise, you might consider doing it in a way that does not mutate the original list. This would be more in line with functional programming practices and would also simplify the code.

Comment: Yes @Mark, but the question demands we perform an in-place algorithm, rather that awarding extra space to a new array

Comment: Fair enough @NobleEugene, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete a value from the list the size changes so you do not need to increment `value`:

```
def removeDuplicates(nums):
        def helper(nums,value=1):
            if value == len(nums):
                return nums
            if(nums[value] == nums[value-1]):
                del nums[value]
                return helper(nums,value) #notice the change here
            else:
                return helper(nums,value+1)
        return helper(nums)
```

This section of code:

```
del nums[value]
return helper(nums,value+1)
```

Causes the function to "skip" a value because an element is removed (changing the item at the index `value`) and `value` is incremented (also changing which item is at index `value`.)

So it should be:

```
del nums[value]
return helper(nums,value)
```

New code output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

However the best way to get the unique values would be:

```
list(set(my_list)) #best
#or
list({k: '' for k in test}.keys())
```

Comment: removeDuplicates([]) => kablooey